# Can I boot already installed Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine on Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualization

I use my computer on dual boot: partition A under Ubuntu 18.04 and partition B under Windows 10. For several reasons, I now think booting into Windows 10 and running Ubuntu in a virtual machine is what best suits me.

**I want this new virtual machine (running in Windows) to boot on the Ubuntu installation I already have installed in partition A.**

Is this possible? If so, **how**?

Comment: See: https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/784138-howto-boot-existing-ubuntu-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows/

Comment: A VM takes quite a bit of ram to run well.  If you have enough ram, you can use the above link, or can just use the Ubuntu ISO and make a new install in VM.  Can make a few VMs and play around with them.

Comment: @George Udosen : Nice source !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run a copy / clone of A-Ubuntu inside a VM hosted by partB-Windows?

Or do you want to run the partA-Ubuntu from a VM hosted by partB-Windows?

Both are possible, first option is harder to maintain. Someone have documented all steps on this site.

The second option is really easy as Linux is friendly :
Dump partA to an image, convert it to a VM VirtualHD, use this VirtualHD with a VM on partB-Windows. you will have to reinstall Grub as it's probably not installed on partA but on mbr... That's as simple
More info if needed